# What is the most efficient way to overlay a second camera with alpha?

Tags: camera, shader

I have two cameras in my scene.

- Camera A needs to be 100% visible.
- Camera B needs to be overlaid over Camera A at 50% opacity.
- Using texture maps is a bit messy because it requires scene geometry to match screen resolution and performance is hit. The texture resolution also needs to be taken into account.

Is there an all shader way to pull two cameras together in a performant way that allows us to mix the opacity of the two cameras?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What platform are you talking about? OpenGL? Some game engine? Typically, a shader doesn't draw cameras. It draws meshes whose positions are projected to the screen with cameras. Are you saying you want a scene drawn with Camera B to be shown at 50% opacity on top of a scene drawn with Camera A? In OpenGL, you would draw the B scene to a FBO and draw the FBO's color texture to the main frame buffer with 50% alpha.

Comment: I really appreciate you responding to my confusing question that was accidentally posted to the wrong stack. I was wondering why nobody was responding to my Unity post on cameras and shaders!

Comment: Haha. Well, it's been a while since I used Unity. I see they allow FBO's (Render Textures in Unity) in the free version now, so now I want to play with it again. I think you would set CameraB's TartgetTexture value to a render texture, and then draw that render texture to the screen after drawing the stuff seen by CameraA. Not sure if this requires a third camera that's orthographic (or a special shader that ignores the camera, and a single quad mesh with coordinates (-1,-1) to (1,1)).